# Docker deploy stops at 'Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)'

Tags: java, docker, gradle

My deployment process just freezes without any error at 'Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)'. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Build the JAR
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as build

WORKDIR /rl-build
# TODO simplify? add .dockerignore with unwanted folders/libraries ?
COPY ./ .

RUN ./gradlew clean build -x integrationTest -x test

# Run the JAR
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot

WORKDIR /rl
COPY --from=build /rl-build/build/libs/interview-service-*.jar ./interview-service.jar

ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0","-jar","/rl/interview-service.jar"]
```

Here is gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.5.4"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id "java"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.owasp.dependencycheck" version "6.5.0.1"
}

group = "com.rocketlawyer.interview"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "Interview Service"
sourceCompatibility = "11"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
    }

    implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20"
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.10"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6"
    implementation 'org.jdbi:jdbi3-sqlobject:3.21.0'
    implementation 'org.jdbi:jdbi3-postgres:3.21.0'
    implementation 'org.jdbi:jdbi3-spring4:3.18.0'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.9"
    implementation 'org.jdbi:jdbi3-json:3.18.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.0.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.8.2'
    implementation 'io.prometheus:simpleclient:0.15.0'

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20"

    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.16.2"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.2"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2:1.4.200"
    testImplementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.14.0"
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.30.1"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2"
    testImplementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.115.1'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.16.2'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:gcloud:1.16.2'
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.1.1'

}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        false
    }
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
    reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir("$buildDir/coverage")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test, integrationTest
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir("$buildDir/jacoco")
        getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
    }
}
project.tasks['dependencyCheckAnalyze'].dependsOn "jacocoTestReport"
project.tasks['sonarqube'].dependsOn "test"
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/jacoco/jacocoTestReport.xml"
    }
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

I'v tried to add additional command in Dockerfile to kill any subsequent daemons, restart computer, update operating system and Docker.

Im running this on Mac ventura 13.2, Apple M1 Max, Docker updated to latest version. Thanks in the advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @dan1st added to main post